# How to find IP address reducer machines in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, ip

How to find reducer IP address in mapping phase in Hadoop
when `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps in mapred-site.xml` set to run mapper and reducer in parallel fashion ?

Comment: It isn't really clear what you need, since the `mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps` property configures when the reducers start running, based on how many of the map tasks have completed.

Comment: I need  know in mapping phase reducers located on which machines? Ip Address or machine name is required